# Formula to check combinations of values in one column to match with combinations in another column

Tags: excel

We do daily reconciliations for over 100 accounts.  I've used match to find the values in column B that match any values in column A.  The issue I have is that most of the time it takes a combination of values in column B to equal to one value in column A or a combination of values in column A.  Is there a way to have excel run all possible combinations of values in column B and check it against all possible combinations of values in column A and match those up?

Here is what the data looks like.  The ones highlighted yellow are an example of what I'd want a formula to help me match up. When added, the 1700 and 765.56 equal the 2465.56 on the other side. Let me know if further clarification would help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VJrD.png)

Thanks!

Comment: An example would help : what you have and what you want to achieve...

Comment: I think I follow (though Solar Mike is right, an example would help). The main thing that one would need is some sort of criteria so the formula knows what constitutes as a valid combination. Definitely account number, but are values separated by date as well? If I have $50 on 9/15 and $30 on 9/16 in column A but $80 on 9/16 in column B, is it okay to combine the 50 and 30 to make 80 and consider the accounts reconciled? That kind of thing. Formulate a criteria so excel knows what's good.

Comment: Is there by chance a column that is always right? I've figured out how to get combinations of B to match A, but it's not able to do combinations of A to match B. If A is always right, then I have an answer, however I'll need to edit the formulas if A can be wrong a lot of the time.

Comment: Dates do not really matter.  On the right side, is the GL side.  These are entered the date credit card charges are entered.  On the left side is the bank side.  The credit card charges take 2-5 days to post there.  So a 6/1 on the right could be matched with a 6/4 on the left, for example. This is what makes this extra difficult.  Column A is right most of the time, as it is what is posted to the bank.  It's a rare occurrence that A is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have this set up with a helper column. Assuming that the example data starts in Data A, the formula is as follows (in column O):

```
=SUMIFS(J:J,H:H,"="&H2,M:M,"="&M2,N:N,N2)
```

This sums up any values in Data B's amount (J:J) when Data B's Date matches the row's date (H:H), when the description matches the row's description (M:M), and if the record type matches the row's description (N:N). With the current data, it only sums 1700 and 765.56 because those are the two records that match the criteria (6/13, Cash Receipt, and Cash). This is the helper column which can be hidden.

Next to this column (column P) is the formula:

```
=IFNA(IF(MATCH(O2,C:C,0)>0, "Reconciled with Row " & MATCH(O2,C:C,0),""),"")
```

This formula will lookup the sum and see if it exists in Data A's amount. If the match does exist then it'll tell you which row in Data A has this amount. If match doesn't find anything then the cell will be blank.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this in a bit and let you know how it works out.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.